# Pandas dataframes equality test

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I write a function that checks two input dataframes are of equal as long as rows in both dataframes are equal? So it disregards index positions and column orders. I can't use df.equals() since it will enforce data types to be equal, which is not what I need.

```
from io import StringIO

canonical_in_csv = """,c,a,b
2,hat,x,1
0,rat,y,4
3,cat,x,2
1,bat,x,2"""

with StringIO(canonical_in_csv) as fp:
    df1 = pd.read_csv(fp, index_col=0)

canonical_soln_csv = """,a,b,c
0,x,1,hat
1,x,2,bat
2,x,2,cat
3,y,4,rat"""

with StringIO(canonical_soln_csv) as fp:
    df2 = pd.read_csv(fp, index_col=0)
```

> df1:

```
    c   a   b
2   hat x   1
0   rat y   4
3   cat x   2
1   bat x   2
```

> df2:

```
    a   b   c
0   x   1   hat
1   x   2   bat
2   x   2   cat
3   y   4   rat
```

My attempt:

```
temp1 = (df == df2).all()
temp2 = temp1.all()
temp2
```

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects

Comment: Why do you want this kind of equality test? May I know the motive

Comment: going through set of practice problems for an online python course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) by index and columns values first, then [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) (`==`) or [`equals`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html):

```
df11 = df1.sort_index().sort_index(axis=1)
df22 = df2.sort_index().sort_index(axis=1)

print (df11.merge(df22))
   a  b    c
0  y  4  rat
1  x  2  bat
2  x  1  hat
3  x  2  cat

print (df11.merge(df22).eq(df11))
      a     b     c
0  True  True  True
1  True  True  True
2  True  True  True
3  True  True  True

a = df11.merge(df22).eq(df11).values.all()
#alternative
#a = df11.merge(df22).equals(df11)
print (a)
True
```

Your function should be rewritten:

```
def checkequality(A, B):

    df11 = A.sort_index(axis=1)
    df11 = df11.sort_values(df11.columns.tolist()).reset_index(drop=True)

    df22 = B.sort_index(axis=1)
    df22 = df22.sort_values(df22.columns.tolist()).reset_index(drop=True)
    return (df11 == df22).values.all()

a = checkequality(df1, df2)
print (a)
True
```

Comment: awesome, much cleaner! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You request on row index dis-regard is pretty difficult to undertake as this datatype is not optimized for such operation whereas regarding columns issue, fortunately this will help you

```
df1.values == df2[df1.columns].values
```

where df1.columns syncs the columns order and values convert to numpy for comparison. I still recommend not doing row re-ordering and match as that can be very taxing for bigger dataset. 
Based on index match this can be what you are looking for

```
df1.values==df2.reindex(df1.index.values.tolist())[df1.columns].values
```

Update

As pointed by @Dark a cleaner and in-place comparison can be done like this

```
df1.loc[df2.index,df2.columns] == df2
```

Comment: If you still need the row index match i can give a snippet based on your index logic but that will be very specific to your usecase/dataset.

Comment: Or maybe  `df1.loc[df2.index,df2.columns] == df2`

Comment: Thats actually cleaner. Let me also add to answer. Great.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out,

```
def checkequality(A, B):

var_names = sorted(A.columns)
var_names
Y = A[var_names].copy()
Y.sort_values(by = var_names,inplace=True)
Y.set_index([list(range(0,len(Y)))],inplace=True)

var_names2 = sorted(B.columns)
var_names2
Y2 = B[var_names2].copy()
Y2.sort_values(by = var_names2,inplace=True)
Y2.set_index([list(range(0,len(Y2)))],inplace=True)

if (Y==Y2).all().all() == True:
    return True
else:
    return False
```